# Create folder if exists Sharepoint suddenly stopped working

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code which was working nicely until recently

```
private async Task<DriveItem> CreateFolderIfNotExists(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string driveId, string folderName)
    {
        try
        {
            var driveItem = new DriveItem
            {
                Name = folderName,
                Folder = new Folder(),
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "fail" }
                }
            };

            return await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Root.Children
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(driveItem);
        }
        catch (ServiceException exception)
        {
            if (exception.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return await this.GetFolderItem(graphClient, driveId, folderName);
        }
    }
```

All of a sudden we are getting this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)     at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)     at xyz.CreateFolderIfNotExists(GraphServiceClient graphClient, String driveId, String folderName) in xyz\Client\SharePointClient.cs:line 63     at xyz.Client.SharePointClient.CopyLegacyFile(String fileId, String destination, String newFileName, String documentLibraryId) xyz\Client\SharePointClient.cs:line 222     at xyz.SharePointDocumentStorage.New() in xtz\SharePointDocumentStorage.cs:line 56     at zzzWorkflowAppService.NewRevision(NewRevisionInput input)     at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationInterceptor.InternalInterceptAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation)     at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InternalInterceptAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation)     at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryInterceptor.InternalInterceptAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation)     at Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.InternalInterceptAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation)     at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.ValidationInterceptor.InternalInterceptAsynchronou...

Any idea whats happening? There was no code push to cause this.

It is not a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my version of [microsoft Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/) which was version 1.21.0 needed to be be upgraded. There must have been a breaking change that was hosted with MS.

Its possible it is related to something like this issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/901